# 405 Method Not Allowed :Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: spring, google-app-engine

I’m getting 405 request method ‘GET’ not supported during file upload at app engine but the same code working ok in my local sandbox

Look like blobservice callback request should be POST Type after **POST /_ah/upload/…** but when I looked with firebug it’s a GET request with following Header I do have request handler define in @Controller class with method type RequestMethod.POST

**Headers**

Response Headersview source 
Allow   POST

Cache-Control   private

Content-Encoding    gzip

Content-Length  179

Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8

Date    Wed, 20 Jun 2012 15:53:18 GMT

Server  Google Frontend

Vary    Accept-Encoding

Request Headersview source

Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7

Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate

Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5

Connection  keep-alive

Cookie  JSESSIONID=ixOug6t1P7FWPDX-eOw5_g

Host    1.xxxx.appspot.com

Referer http://1.xxxx.appspot.com/asset_upload

User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1

**env: spring mvc+tiles2**

I really appreciated any suggestion  to slove or new way of uploading file to google app engine

Answer (score 1):

The URL you specify in createUploadURL will be POSTed to after the upload is complete - are you certain that this URL has a POST handler?

Comment: Thank you, yes I have tried POST, GET and both POST/GET handler. I guess UrlBasedViewResolver is what giving me this trouble, I have tiles plus spring integration